# "Popping" a value from a HashSet

Tags: rust, hashset, borrow-checker

I can't seem to find a way to pop a (random) value from a `HashSet`. Inspired by other code samples, I wrote the following:

```
my_set.iter().next().map(|i| my_set.take(i).unwrap())
```

I.e get an iterator on the set's values, take the first value (a reference) from it, and then run `my_set.take()` using the reference previously obtained, to get the value itself (not the reference) and remove it from the set.

This doesn't compile due to:

```
error[E0500]: closure requires unique access to `my_set` but it is already borrowed
   |
32 |         my_set.iter().next().map(|i| my_set.take(i).unwrap())
   |         ------               --- ^^^ ------ second borrow occurs due to use of `my_set` in closure
   |         |                    |   |
   |         |                    |   closure construction occurs here
   |         |                    first borrow later used by call
   |         borrow occurs here
```

I've tried many, many variations on this, but they all fail due to an immutable borrow then being borrowed as mutable (error 502).

Can any one recommend a way to rewrite the above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove any element from a HashSet and get ownership (random order is fine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63759800/remove-any-element-from-a-hashset-and-get-ownership-random-order-is-fine)

Answer (score 5):

If you're okay with cloning the item removed you can do:

```
let elem = set.iter().next().unwrap().clone();
set.remove(&elem);
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=389b220acbab1531e4fee042124a5158)</sup>

Or with a guard against the set being empty:

```
if let Some(elem) = set.iter().next().cloned() {
    set.remove(&elem);
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=640f48bdd825bab6e51ea9c862b87855)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes that works...but I'm curious: isn't there a more elegant approach that doesn't require cloning?

Comment: @Maan hashset from std is forgotten I don't know why I advice use hashmap directly or use some crate

Comment: If you don't want to clone, you could use `if let Some(elem) = set.iter().next() { let elem = set.take(elem).unwrap();`. It's annoying to have to search for an item that has already been found, though (both with remove or take).

Answer (score 0):

This feels hacky, but you can use [`HashSet::retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.retain) with an impure function:

```rust
let mut flag = false;
my_set.retain(|_| mem::replace(&mut flag, true));
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9c21be1eea17e00bd928120b69d48988))

The element removed is truly arbitrary — I ran the code on the playground a few times, and obtained different results.

---

As interjay mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68825244/popping-a-value-from-a-hashset/68826400?noredirect=1#comment121653682_68826400), this approach iterates over the entire set just to remove one value, so the cost is generally more significant than cloning one value.  Therefore, only use this workaround when the element really cannot be cloned.

Comment: This will iterate over the entire set to remove one value.